# Combing Submatrices into a single matrix

Tags: java, matrix

For an assignment I have to get two matrices, A and B, from a text file (matrix.txt).I must then split the matrices into submatrices

ex

```
A = {{A00, A01}, {A10, A11}}
```

Once that is done to both matrix A and B, I must add the two corresponding submatrices together to get the submatrices for matrix C.

ex.

```
C00 = (A00 + B00)
C01 = (A01 + B01)
C10 = (A10 + B10)
C11 = (A11 + B11)

C = {{C00, C01}, {C10, C11}}
```

I have been able to get everything done except for merging the C submatrice back into the matrix C.

Here is an example of matrix.txt

```
4 7
2 3 1 2 5 1 2
3 1 2 2 2 4 4
1 2 3 2 7 2 1
3 6 1 5 1 3 5
6 5 4 1 4 3 1
3 3 2 2 1 1 2
7 5 4 3 2 5 3
2 1 8 4 8 4 4
```

Here is my code so far

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MatrixThread {
        
    public static Scanner scan;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
            if(args.length == 0){
            System.out.println("File name not specified");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        
        try{
            File matrix = new File(args[0]);
            scan = new Scanner(matrix);
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            System.err.println("Cannot open file.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        ThreadOperation Operation = new ThreadOperation();
        Operation.executeOperation();
        
    }
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

mport java.util.Arrays;

class ThreadOperation extends MatrixThread {
    
    
    void executeOperation(){
        
        int N = scan.nextInt();
        int M = scan.nextInt();
            
        int A[][] = new int [N][M];
        int B[][] = new int [N][M];
        //System.out.println(N + " " + M);
    
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
            {               
                if(scan.hasNextInt())
                {
                    A[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
                }
            }
        }
                
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
            {               
                if(scan.hasNextInt())
                {
                    B[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
                }
            }
        }
        
        /*int C[][] = new int [N][M];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < M; j++){
                C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
                System.out.print(C[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\r\n");
        }*/
        
        int halfRow = N/2;
        int halfCol = M/2;
        int remainingRow = N - halfRow;
        int remainingCol = M - halfCol;
        
        //System.out.print(halfRow + " " + halfCol + " " + remainingRow + " " + remainingCol);
        //System.out.println(" ");
        //System.out.println(" ");
        
        int A00[][] = new int[halfRow][halfCol];
        for (int i = 0; i < halfRow; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < halfCol; j++){
                A00[i][j] = A[i][j];
                //System.out.print(A00[i][j] + " ");
            }
            //System.out.print("\r\n");
        }
        
        //System.out.println(" ");
        
        int A10[][] = new int[remainingRow][halfCol];
        for (int i = halfRow; i < N; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < halfCol; j++){
                A10[i - halfRow][j] = A[i][j];
                //System.out.print(A10[i - halfRow][j] + " ");
            }
            //System.out.print("\r\n");
        }
        
        //System.out.println(" ");
        
        int A01[][] = new int[halfRow][remainingCol];
        for (int i = 0; i < halfRow; i++) {
            for (int j = halfCol; j < M; j++){
                A01[i][j - halfCol] = A[i][j];
                //System.out.print(A01[i][j - halfCol] + " ");
            }
            //System.out.print("\r\n");
        }
        
        //System.out.println(" ");
        
        int A11[][] = new int[remainingRow][remainingCol];
        for (int i = halfRow; i < N; i++) {
            for(int j = halfCol; j < M; j++) {
                A11[i - halfRow][j - halfCol] = A[i][j];
                //System.out.print(A11[i - halfRow][j - halfCol] + " ");
            }
            //System.out.print("\r\n");
        }
        
        //System.out.println(" ");
        
        int B00[][] = new int[halfRow][halfCol];
        for (int i = 0; i < halfRow; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < halfCol; j++){
                B00[i][j] = B[i][j];
                //System.out.print(B00[i][j] + " ");
            }
            //System.out.print("\r\n");
        }
        
        //System.out.println(" ");
        
        int B10[][] = new int[remainingRow][halfCol];
        for (int i = halfRow; i < N; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < halfCol; j++){
                B10[i - halfRow][j] = B[i][j];
                //System.out.print(B10[i - halfRow][j] + " ");
            }
            //System.out.print("\r\n");
        }
        
        //System.out.println(" ");
        
        int B01[][] = new int[halfRow][remainingCol];
        for (int i = 0; i < halfRow; i++) {
            for (int j = halfCol; j < M; j++){
                B01[i][j - halfCol] = B[i][j];
                //System.out.print(B01[i][j - halfCol] + " ");
            }
            //System.out.print("\r\n");
        }
        
        //System.out.println(" ");
        
        int B11[][] = new int[remainingRow][remainingCol];
        for (int i = halfRow; i < N; i++) {
            for(int j = halfCol; j < M; j++) {
                B11[i - halfRow][j - halfCol] = B[i][j];
                //System.out.print(B11[i - halfRow][j - halfCol] + " ");
            }
            //System.out.print("\r\n");
        }
        //System.out.println();
    
        int C00[][] = new int [halfRow][halfCol];
    
        for (int i = 0; i < halfRow; i++){
            for ( int j = 0; j < halfCol; j++){
                C00[i][j]  = A00[i][j] + B00[i][j];
                System.out.print(C00[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
                int C01[][] = new int [halfRow][remainingCol];
    
        for (int i = 0; i < halfRow; i++){
            for ( int j = 0; j < remainingCol; j++){
                C01[i][j]  = A01[i][j] + B01[i][j];
                System.out.print(C01[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        int C10[][] = new int [remainingRow][halfCol];
    
        for (int i = 0; i < remainingRow; i++){
            for ( int j = 0; j < halfCol; j++){
                C10[i][j]  = A10[i][j] + B10[i][j];
                System.out.print(C10[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    int [][] C0 = new int [halfRow][M];
    int [][] C1 = new int [remainingRow][M];
    System.arraycopy(C00, 0, C0, 0, remainingCol);
    System.arraycopy(C10, 0, C1, 0, remainingCol);
    System.arraycopy(C01, halfCol, C0, 0, remainingCol);
    System.arraycopy(C11, halfCol, C1, 0, remainingCol);
    System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(C0));
    System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(C1));
    }
}
```

The error I am currently getting is `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Here is an example of the desired output for every matrix based on the example matrix.txt file I provided

```
 N = 4, M = 7

Matrix A:
2 3 1 2 5 1 2
3 1 2 2 2 4 4
1 2 3 2 7 2 1
3 6 1 5 1 3 5 

Matrix B:
6 5 4 1 4 3 1 
3 3 2 2 1 1 2 
7 5 4 3 2 5 3 
2 1 8 4 8 4 4

Submatrix A00:
2 3 1 2
3 1 2 2 
Submatrix A01:
5 1 2
2 4 4
Submatrix A10:
1 2 3 2
3 6 1 5
Submatrix A11:
7 2 1
1 3 5
Submatrix B00:
6 5 4 1 
3 3 2 2
Submatrix B01:
4 3 1
1 1 2
Submatrix B10:
7 5 4 3 
2 1 8 4
Submatrix B11:
2 5 3
8 4 4
Submatrix C00:
8 8 5 3
6 4 4 4 
Submatrix C01:
9 4 3
3 5 6 
Submatrix C10:
8 7 7 5
5 7 9 9
Submatrix C11:
9 7 4 
9 7 9

Matrix C:
8 8 5 3 9 4 3
6 4 4 4 3 5 6
8 7 7 5 9 7 4 
5 7 9 9 9 7 9
```

Comment: From the given input, can you add how the A and B sub matrices would look like, with 4, 7

Comment: @Sabraeesh Muralidharan I just updated and added how all the matrices should look

Comment: Sorry, I still couldn't generalize it, if you i/p is 4X7 then we need to split A and B as 4X7 but is there a rule for A00, A01 size??

Comment: The rule for the size of A00, A01 is that they have to be similar in size, close to [N/2][M/2]. So in my code the variables for the size of the submatrices are halfRow, halfCol, remainingRow, & remainingCol.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I have added my answer it.. hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

I could see below things are contradicting the expectations,

```
1. When Row, Col = {4, 7} A00={2, 4}, A01={2, 3}
```

Hence modify calculation like below,

```
int halfRow = (N % 2 == 0) ? (N/2) : (N/2 + 1);
int halfCol = (M % 2 == 0) ? (M/2) : (M/2 + 1);
int remainingRow = N - halfRow;
int remainingCol = M - halfCol;
```

Also,

```
2. C11 calculation was missing, not sure if it was missed just while pasting the code in SO
```

Hence, I have included those here,

```
static void executeOperation() {

    int N = scan.nextInt();
    int M = scan.nextInt();

    int[][] A = new int[N][M];
    int[][] B = new int[N][M];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j) {
            if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                A[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j) {
            if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                B[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }

    int halfRow = (N % 2 == 0) ? (N/2) : (N/2 + 1);
    int halfCol = (M % 2 == 0) ? (M/2) : (M/2 + 1);
    int remainingRow = N - halfRow;
    int remainingCol = M - halfCol;

    int[][] A00 = new int[halfRow][halfCol];
    for (int i = 0; i < halfRow; i++) {
        if (halfCol >= 0)
            System.arraycopy(A[i], 0, A00[i], 0, halfCol);
    }

    int[][] A10 = new int[remainingRow][halfCol];
    for (int i = halfRow; i < N; i++) {
        if (halfCol >= 0)
            System.arraycopy(A[i], 0, A10[i - halfRow], 0, halfCol);
    }

    int[][] A01 = new int[halfRow][remainingCol];
    for (int i = 0; i < halfRow; i++) {
        if (M - halfCol >= 0)
            System.arraycopy(A[i], halfCol, A01[i], 0, M - halfCol);
    }

    int[][] A11 = new int[remainingRow][remainingCol];
    for (int i = halfRow; i < N; i++) {
        if (M - halfCol >= 0)
            System.arraycopy(A[i], halfCol, A11[i - halfRow], 0, M - halfCol);
    }

    System.out.println(" ");

    int[][] B00 = new int[halfRow][halfCol];
    for (int i = 0; i < halfRow; i++) {
        if (halfCol >= 0)
            System.arraycopy(B[i], 0, B00[i], 0, halfCol);
    }

    int[][] B10 = new int[remainingRow][halfCol];
    for (int i = halfRow; i < N; i++) {
        if (halfCol >= 0)
            System.arraycopy(B[i], 0, B10[i - halfRow], 0, halfCol);
    }

    int[][] B01 = new int[halfRow][remainingCol];
    for (int i = 0; i < halfRow; i++) {
        if (M - halfCol >= 0)
            System.arraycopy(B[i], halfCol, B01[i], 0, M - halfCol);
    }

    int[][] B11 = new int[remainingRow][remainingCol];
    for (int i = halfRow; i < N; i++) {
        if (M - halfCol >= 0)
            System.arraycopy(B[i], halfCol, B11[i - halfRow], 0, M - halfCol);
    }

    int[][] C00 = new int[halfRow][halfCol];

    for (int i = 0; i < halfRow; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < halfCol; j++) {
            C00[i][j] = A00[i][j] + B00[i][j];
        }
    }
    int[][] C01 = new int[halfRow][remainingCol];

    for (int i = 0; i < halfRow; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < remainingCol; j++) {
            C01[i][j] = A01[i][j] + B01[i][j];
        }
    }
    int[][] C10 = new int[remainingRow][halfCol];

    for (int i = 0; i < remainingRow; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < halfCol; j++) {
            C10[i][j] = A10[i][j] + B10[i][j];
        }
    }

    int[][] C11 = new int[remainingRow][remainingCol];

    for (int i = 0; i < remainingRow; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < remainingCol; j++) {
            C11[i][j] = A11[i][j] + B11[i][j];
        }
    }

    int[][] C0 = new int[halfRow][M];
    int[][] C1 = new int[halfRow][M];
    cloneArray(C00, 0, C0, 0);
    cloneArray(C01, halfCol, C0, 0);
    cloneArray(C10, 0, C1, 0);
    cloneArray(C11, halfCol, C1, 0);

    int[][] C = new int[N][M];
    cloneArray(C0, 0, C, 0);
    cloneArray(C1, 0, C, halfRow);

    System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(C));
}

private static void cloneArray(int[][] src, int destPos, int[][] target, int tarPos) {
    int length = src.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        System.arraycopy(src[i], 0, target[i+tarPos], destPos, src[i].length);
    }
}
```

Input:

```
4 7
2 3 1 2 5 1 2
3 1 2 2 2 4 4
1 2 3 2 7 2 1
3 6 1 5 1 3 5
6 5 4 1 4 3 1
3 3 2 2 1 1 2
7 5 4 3 2 5 3
2 1 8 4 8 4 4
```

Output:

```
[[8, 8, 5, 3, 9, 4, 3],
 [6, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 6],
 [8, 7, 7, 5, 9, 7, 4],
 [5, 7, 9, 9, 9, 7, 9]]
```

Hope it helps..